# TempData and Session both null after RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, session-state, tempdata

This is a weird one. Both TempData and Session work fine for the most part, but, if you access the website via a link from within Outlook Web (the link must be within an HTML email), then both TempData and Session lose their values after redirection.

As an example, create a new ASP.NET Core MVC Project with Visual Studio 2022, running on .NET Core 8, and replace the Program.cs and HomeController.cs with the following. Also add the Test.cshtml view. Then try building and running this code (built with Visual Studio 2022, running on .NET Core 8).

It will run fine. But then send yourself an HTML formatted email, with a link to the website embedded (running on localhost) and see what happens. When you click on that link and hit the site, both TempData and Session will be null after the redirection.

**HomeController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication10.Models;

namespace WebApplication10.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("One");
        }

        public IActionResult One()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Two");
        }

        public IActionResult Two()
        {
            CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
            {
                Path = "/",
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30),
                Secure = true,
                HttpOnly = true
            };
            Response.Cookies.Append("Oatmeal", "877", cookieOptions);

            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("USERID", 877);
            TempData["TEST"] = "HELLO";

            return RedirectToAction("Test");
        }   

        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            var cookie = Request.Cookies["Oatmeal"];
            TempData["USERID"] = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("USERID");
            return View();
        }   

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Globalization;
using WebApplication10.Data;

namespace WebApplication10
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3;

                // Lockout settings        
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                // Sign-in settings
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            });

            builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Path = "/",
                    Name = "TestAuthCookie",
                    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                    IsEssential = true,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
                };
            });

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Manage");
            });         

            builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(options =>
            {
                options.ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.SizeLimit = 100;
                options.CompactionPercentage = 0.2;
            });
            builder.Services.AddResponseCaching();
            builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
                options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            });
            builder.Services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "TEMPDATA";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;        
            });

            builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "TESTSESSION";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseResponseCaching();
            app.UseRouting();

            CookiePolicyOptions cookiePolicy = new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
                Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                CheckConsentNeeded = context => false
            };

            app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicy);

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US")
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.MapBlazorHub();
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Views/Home/Test.cshtml**

```
<p>@TempData["TEST"]</p>
<p>@TempData["USERID"]</p>
```

Comment: "if you access the website via a link from within Outlook Web (the link must be within an HTML email), then both TempData and Session lose their values after redirection." How do you do these two steps ?  'When you click on that link and hit the site, both TempData and Session will be null after the redirection" What's  the redirection ? How ?

Comment: If you look at the code, you'll see that there are four actions: Index, One, Two and Test. Each action redirects to the next one. TempData is set in "Two" and lost in "Test". To test the email link, email yourself the link using an html anchor. Then run the project in debug, and click the link. As you step through the code, you can watch the value of TempData (and Session).

Comment: I test your code, if run the project in debug then see the  value of TempData (and Session), but I don't know where to put the  email link, and when to click it.

Comment: My site runs from the following url:  https://localhost:7032 so I just emailed myself this  <a href="https://localhost:7032/Home/">Click here...</a> and then I click that link in the email I received.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is all due to **SameSiteMode**. When it is set to **Strict**, everything breaks when loading the site via a link clicked on from an external application. I had to set all my cookies to **SameSiteMode.Lax**.